# How to design an extremely fast python HTTP API with data lookup (>15K req/sec)?

Tags: python, heroku, sqlite, webserver, sanic

I need to build a REST API/server which responds to more than HTTP GET 15,000 requests per seconds in under 80ms. If necessary I could run multiple instances with a load balancer.

The server gets a request with a list of criteria (around 20), they need to be parsed and compared to a ruleset (about 2000 rules which have different values for all 20 criteria and a final decision) which decides the response (yes or no).

Sample Request payload:

```
{"Country" : "DE",
 "ID" : "998423-423432-4234234-234234",
 "Criteria1": "8748r78",
 "Criteria2": "Some String",
  [...]
}
```

Sample ruleset (still to be decided, but let's start with a simple design):

```
+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| RuleId | Country |  Criteria1  |  Criteria2   | etc...
+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
|      1 | UK      | SomeString1 | SomeString3  |
|      2 | UK      | SomeString1 | SomeString2  |
|      3 | US      | SomeString4 | * (Wildcard) |
+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Every criteria can contain between 1 and probably around 400 different values, all strings (e.g. GEOs in ISO Code). Some might be empty and be treated as wildcards. Theoretically there could be entries with all 20 criterias having the same value, but that is a topic for the yet to be written rule engine to sort out.

I did some research how to achieve this:

1. Using sanic as a webserver for a high throughput, according to my
   research this is the fastest for python excluding japronto which is
   in alpha; Edit: Does anyone has experience with the performance of a python based webserver+webframework regarding a similar usecase? I only read benchmarks which usually have a very simple testcase (just respond a fixed string to a request, therefore the high number of possible requests per second in all the benchmarks)
2. Using sqlite3 (in memory) for rule lookup; not sure if a SQL statement with 20 constraints is fast enough? Maybe there is another
   way to compare every request to the ruleset over 20 criteria (each
   one is a string comparison). EDIT: Thanks to a commenter I might precompute the rules into hashes and use hashes for lookup, thus a database for the real-time lookup is not needed.
3. Use redis or another database to store the rules precomputed (that
   is another topic) and make them ready to get loaded in every
       instance/worker of the http server and thus sqlite3 database.
4. Maybe use pypy3 for additional speedup, but I have no experience
   with pypy

I would host this on Heroku.

So the question is: Which libraries and thus architecture would allow that kind of speed with python?

Comment: Can you give us an example request and an example rule? How are you determining which rule to apply - closest match to given criteria, ie Cartesian distance? How "dense" is the rule set, ie what is the expected greatest distance between a request and its closest matching rule? How often does the rule set change?

Comment: 2000 rules is *tiny*. I'd use some in-memory hash table.

Comment: ... also note that Sanic is listed as "pre-alpha" on PyPi - I'm not sure I'd want to trust it in production yet.

Comment: @HughBothwell Added examples (no code yet, just a primitive beginning for the data structure). I am most concerned with the 80ms deadline for the whole roundtrip.

Comment: @CL. Very good idea, I could hash all the rules and then hash the request and get an extremely fast lookup..

Comment: So can we expect all specified request strings to be exact matches to rule strings? Or will there be predictable partial matches (ie `rule.startswith(criteria)`) or unpredictable ones (ie editdistance)?

Comment: @HughBothwell I think it is always exact match, there might be the case of a list of values (a criteria contains not a single value, but a list of values where only one has to match; a whitelist), but I guess I could just create additional rules for that with each variation..

Comment: What's the likelihood of you getting duplicate requests?

Comment: @disflux None. Every request is unique and needs a response in 80ms or less (round trip time). Every request is only valid once (in time) and thus there are no duplicates (every request belongs to a real time event).

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that

1. all given criteria are exact string matches
2. all unspecified criteria match anything (wildcard)
3. we can discard all rules which produce False
4. rules may contain None which matches anything (wildcard)
5. the result is True if there is at least one rule that matches all given criteria, else False

We can build a fast look-up as a dict (column) of dict (value) of set (matching rule ids):

```
from collections import namedtuple

WILDCARD = None

Rule = namedtuple("Rule", ["Country", "Criteria1", "Criteria2"])

rules = [
    Rule("UK", "Somestring1", "Somestring3"),
    Rule("UK", "Somestring1", "Somestring2"),
    Rule("US", "Somestring4", WILDCARD)
]

def build_lookup(rules):
    columns = Rule._fields
    # create lookup table (special handling of wildcard entries)
    lookup = {column: {WILDCARD: set()} for column in columns}
    # index rules by criteria
    for id, rule in enumerate(rules):
        for column, value in zip(columns, rule):
            if value in lookup[column]:
                lookup[column][value].add(id)
            else:
                lookup[column][value] = {id}
    return lookup

rule_lookup = build_lookup(rules)
```

With the given sample data, `rule_lookup` now contains

```
{
    'Country':   {WILDCARD: set(), 'UK': {0, 1}, 'US': {2}},
    'Criteria1': {WILDCARD: set(), 'Somestring1': {0, 1}, 'Somestring4': {2}},
    'Criteria2': {WILDCARD: {2}, 'Somestring2': {1}, 'Somestring3': {0}}
}
```

then we can quickly match criteria to rules like

```
def all_matching_rules(criteria):
    """
    criteria is a dict of {column: value} to match

    Return a set of all rule ids which match criteria
    """
    if criteria:
        result = empty = set()
        first = True
        for column, value in criteria.items():
            ids = rule_lookup[column].get(value, empty) | rule_lookup[column][WILDCARD]
            if first:
                result = ids
                first = False
            else:
                result &= ids   # find intersection of sets
            # short-circuit evaluation if result is null set
            if not result:
                break
        return result
    else:
        # no criteria, return everything
        return set(range(len(rules)))

def any_rule_matches(criteria):
    """
    criteria is a dict of {column: value} to match

    Return True if any rule matches criteria, else False
    """
    if criteria:
        return bool(all_matching_rules(criteria))
    else:
        return bool(len(rules))
```

which runs like

```
>>> all_matching_rules({"Country": "UK", "Criteria2": "Somestring8"})
set()

>>> all_matching_rules({"Country": "US", "Criteria2": "Somestring8"})
{2}

>>> any_rule_matches({"Country": "UK", "Criteria2": "Somestring8"})
False

>>> any_rule_matches({"Country": "US", "Criteria2": "Somestring8"})
True
```

Timeit reports that this runs in about 930ns on my machine - should be plenty fast enough ;-)